# Pointers in UML Diagram

Tags: c++, uml, class-diagram

I am creating a text based fantasy game in C++. I have used pointers, and a weapon and armor object. How would I put these in the UML Diagram?

Below is my attempt, but I don't believe it is formatted correctly.

As in my Player.h file:

```
Item* item1; 
Item* item2; 
Weapon w; //Weapon object
Armor a; //Armor object
```

Here is how I formatted them on the UML (they are all public):

```
+ Item* item1 
+ Item* item2 
+ Weapon w 
+ Armor a
```

Comment: Pointers. Nice. Where to?

Comment: Item* points to item 1 and item 2 since the user is allowed to have 2 items

Comment: Can you show the actual UML diagram instead of simply some list (which is basically the same as your actual code)

Comment: My glass bowl unfortunately broke. So, again, what IS `Item`?

Answer (score 2):

The fact you use a pointer can be relevant for a given programming language but not in general, nor for UML. Of course this is relevant in C++ (even through hidden/shared/... pointer) but not in Java for instance where there are only pointers.

Anyway the fact this is not relevant in UML does not mean you cannot generate the code you want through a UML modeler.

In your example the instances memorized by *w* and *a* disappear when the instance of your class disappear, the right way to model that in UML is to use *compositions*.

At contrario if the instances of *item* continue to live when the instance of the class disappear you have to use a simple *association* or an *aggregation* but not a composition. In that case by definition that means you use pointers in C++ (whatever the way the pointer is supported), example :

[image]

Comment: Where from do you know that `Item` is a class instance? It can be anything: a structure or via Alias (I'd guess that c++ has such syntactical sugar) some integer or array of who-knows. That's why I asked the OP about "Pointers".

Comment: When I said "_if the instances ..._" the fact one can speak about instance is also conditional. From the OP question I just know the type in the C++ source is _item_ and that without multiplicity indication (so 1 element by default rather than an array). After if _item_ corresponds for instance to an _int_ through a _typedef_, in UML the definition of _type_ will be done through a class and the diagram is still relevant ;-) I just try to give material to the OP rather than just to only say _to speak about pointer in UML is not relevant_

Comment: @qwerty_so in C++ a struct is a class in which all members are public.  If it would be an alias, there would be another type hidden behind but semantically, Bruno's diagram would still be valid. The array would only change the multiplicity of the link., but Bruno's absence of multiplicity is as open as the OP's code.  Of course, we do not know how the item relates to the other classes, nor what is the containing class that Bruno called CI.  We can only be as expressive as the OP, not more ;-)

Comment: @Christophe I'm always reluctant to answer a question which in itself is not clear. So will be the answer. Others can be mislead. So I ask posters to clarify before giving an answer. Obviously the OP is gone after a single question.